# Dart's runZoned - how is it different than async await

Tags: dart, dart-async

So I've read the docs and this example in particular:

```dart
runZoned(() {
  HttpServer.bind('0.0.0.0', port).then((server) {
    server.listen(staticFiles.serveRequest);
  });
},
onError: (e, stackTrace) => print('Oh noes! $e $stackTrace'));
```

I understand the whole zone-local-values thing, and the sort of AOP option of tracing code through a zone - enter/exit.

But other than that, is the code block above any different than:

```dart
try {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind('0.0.0.0', port);
  server.listen(staticFiles.serveRequest);
} catch (e, stackTrace) {
  print('Oh noes! $e ${e.stackTrace}');
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your code is not valid Dart. I think the first code is missing some `runZoned` call, and the second code should probably use `on Exception catch (e)` to catch the exception.
Please update with the correct code.

Comment: @lrn Thanks, the runZoned was at the level of the backticks, fixed it. Also fixed the exception issue.

Comment: Should probably do `catch (e, stackTrace)` to match the first example, because `Exception`s won't have a `.stackTrace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runZoned` code introduces a new uncaught error handler.

Some asynchronous errors do not happen in a context where they can be thrown to user code. For example, if you create a future, but never `await` it or listen to it in any other way, and that future then completes with an error, that error is considered "uncaught" or "unhandled". Futures work using callbacks, and there has been no callback provided that it can call.

In that case, the current zone's uncaught error handler is invoked with the error.

Your first example introduces such a handler, which means that if the body of the `runZoned` call has any uncaught async errors, you'll be told about them.
That includes the future returned by calling `then`, but also any other asynchronous errors that may happen (if any).

When you await a future, and *that* future completes with an error, that error is (re)thrown, an can be caught. The `try`/`catch` of the second example will catch that error (and any thrown by calling `listen`, which shouldn't be any as long as `server` isn't `null`, which it shouldn't be).

So, the difference is only really in whether uncaught asynchronous errors are handled. (And how any errors in the `catch` code is propagated, because an error happening during an uncaught-error zone handler will again be uncaught.)

Comment: Thanks!
I want to clarify that I understood correctly:

So essentially there is no actual difference, except the semantic difference of caught vs uncaught exceptions. That is, runZoned has an uncaught error handler that notifies us of uncaught errors in the code. Whereas the catch block is intended to catch such errors, rendering them "caught" exceptions.

Is that correct?

Comment: Not precisely. Some errors happen outside of the normal control flow. Perhaps in a future which is *not* awaited, or in a callback which has no other way to report an error. Those are unhandled *async* errors. The `runZoned` introduces a new handler for those errors, the `try`/`catch` does not.

Comment: Interesting. So essentially if we suspect the function has some side effects, and we want to make sure our application doesn't crash, using runZoned with an uncaught error handler is a way to make sure we're safe. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if you expect unhandled async errors, then you can handle them using `runZoned`. However, those *are* errors, and ignoring them might not be the best approach. Using `runZoned` is something I'd reserve for frameworks, which run unknown user code in a context and want to keep the context alive even if the user code has errors. It's not something I'd use in any program, just to be extra defensive.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it in some library code that uses Apache Hive behind the scenes, so that makes sense. Thanks for the interesting discussion :)